# oracle - PLS-00103 & ORA -06550 on procedures

Tags: oracle, ora-06550, pls-00103

I'm getting the above error while trying to run a simple PL/SQL program that uses procedures. I dont know what went wrong, please help out.

```
declare
    create or replace procedure palindrome (x in number,y out number) is
    i integer;
    j integer;
    k integer:=0;
begin
    i:=x;
    while i>0
    loop
        j:=mod(i,10);
        k:=k*10+j;
        i:=i/10;
    end loop;
    y:=k;
end;
begin
    x integer:=121;
    y integer;
    palindrome(x,y);
    dbms_output.put_line(y);
end;
```

/
ERROR at line 2:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma
>   procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifications to your code.

```
  create or replace procedure palindrome (x in number,y out number) is
    i integer;
    j integer;
    k integer:=0;

begin
    i:=x;
    while i>0
    loop
        j:=mod(i,10);
        k:=k*10+j;
        i:=i/10;
    end loop;
    y:=k;
    dbms_output.put_line(y);
end;
```

/

Execute that procedure

```
declare
y number;
begin
 palindrome(133,y);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need `DECLARE` when you're creating an anonymous PL/SQL block that contains variable declarations. When you're creating a named procedure/function/package, then your `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` statement takes the place of the `DECLARE`. Anything between that statement and the corresponding `BEGIN` is known as the declaration section.

It's not especially clear if you're trying to create a named procedure that you can then call with another PL/SQL anonymous block, in which case you'd do:

```
create or replace procedure palindrome (x in number,y out number) is
    i integer;
    j integer;
    k integer:=0;
begin
    i:=x;
    while i>0
    loop
        j:=mod(i,10);
        k:=k*10+j;
        i:=i/10;
    end loop;
    y:=k;
end;
/

declare
    x integer := 121;
    y integer;
begin
    palindrome(x,y);
    dbms_output.put_line(y);
end;
/
```

or if you're trying to declare a procedure inside an anonymous PL/SQL, in which case you'd do:

```
declare
    x integer := 121;
    y integer;

    procedure palindrome (x in number, y out number) is
        i integer;
        j integer;
        k integer := 0;
    begin
        i := x;
        while i > 0
        loop
            j := mod(i,10);
            k := k*10 + j;
            i := i/10;
        end loop;
        y := k;
    end palindrome;
begin
    palindrome(x,y);
    dbms_output.put_line(y);
end;
/
```

Comment: Not a tutorial, no. But I can suggest the [PL/SQL reference manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) and Steven Feuerstein's book [Oracle PL/SQL Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Oracle-SQL-Programming-Steven-Feuerstein/dp/1449324452/)